# TYPO3-Slug not working with multiple arguments in f:link.action

Tags: typo3, fluid, slug, typo3-9.x

I try to create speaking URL out of an action-link in TYPO3 9.5 to let the next page know from where the user came from.

When I use this code for the action-link:

```
<f:link.action pageUid="296" action="show" controller="Author" arguments="{author : blogentry.author, categoryParent : filtercategories.uid}"> {blogentry.author.firstname} {blogentry.author.surename}
</f:link.action>
```

and this in my config.yaml:

```
BlogAuthorPluginShow:
  type: Extbase
  extension: Blog
  plugin: Blogauthors
  routes:
    - routePath: '/{author_title}'
      _controller: 'Author::show'
      _arguments:
        'author_title': author
  defaultController: 'Author::list'
  aspects:
    author_title:
      type: PersistedAliasMapper
      tableName: 'tx_ivsblog_domain_model_author'
      routeFieldName: 'pathsegment'
```

it doesn't work because of the second argument (`, categoryParent : filtercategories.uid`). If I remove the second argument and write it like this it works:

```
<f:link.action pageUid="296" action="show" controller="Author" arguments="{author : blogentry.author}"
> {blogentry.author.firstname} {blogentry.author.surename}
</f:link.action>
```

How can I manage it to give the controller a second argument and make the slug work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument `categoryParent` is not registered in `config.yaml`.
I'm not sure if it's enough to register it and use it there but i'd consider it as minimum requirement.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can i register a second one?

Comment: in the same kind like you did with `author_title` and the `categoryParent` needs then some path-segment in the URL too.

Comment: something like this: `routePath: '/{author_title}'-{category_parent}`

Comment: Perfect! i added this:

´´´
      - routePath: '/{author_title}-{category_parent}'
´´´
and this 
´´´
          'category_parent': categoryParent
´´´
and this 
´´´
      category_parent:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: 'sys_category'
        routeFieldName: 'title'
´´´
Thank you!

Comment: great, thanks for the feedback, will help others too!