# TYPO3 RouteEnhancer with custom ValueMapper

Tags: routes, typo3, extbase, typo3-9.x

I'm currenty trying to implement a custom RouteEnhancer.

Is it just me, or is the documentation horribly incomplete again? I haven't been able to find any information about custom enhancers in TYPO3 other than a meager paragraph in the changelog entry, where can I get more information about these? I can't event find them in the API documentation.

The relevant part of my domain model in my extension is `Termin` and `Veranstaltung`.
Theres a `n to 1` relation type from `termin->veranstaltung`.  My `Veranstaltung->showAction()` accepts a `termin` as parameter. I've started with the default PersistedAliasMapper and that worked okay for the `uid`s of `Termin`. Unfortunately the actual title is in the `Veranstaltung` entity.

I've come up with these simple converters and set my config up to use them. I have two problems:

- The generated URL still has a cHash,
  `veranstaltung/81?cHash=fba7f1194090a8400556257a4cfe6f3b`.
  How do I get rid of that?
- The resolver doesn't seem to work at all. I've debugged the return value and there seems to be nothing wrong with it. `resolve()` expects me to return the entities `uid` as string, right?

TerminValueMapper.php:

```php
<?php
namespace REDACTED\REDACTEDVeranstaltungen\Routing\Aspect;

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Routing\Aspect\PersistedMappableAspectInterface;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Site\SiteLanguageAwareTrait;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\ConnectionPool;

class TerminValueMapper implements PersistedMappableAspectInterface
{
    use SiteLanguageAwareTrait;

    /**
     * @param string $value
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function generate(string $value): ?string
    {
        if($uid=intval($value)){

            $queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getQueryBuilderForTable('tx_REDACTEDveranstaltungen_domain_model_termin');
            $statement = $queryBuilder
               ->select('t.uid', 'v.titel', 'v.urltitel', 't.beginn')
               ->from('tx_REDACTEDveranstaltungen_domain_model_termin','t')
               ->leftJoin('t', 'tx_REDACTEDveranstaltungen_domain_model_veranstaltung', 'v', 't.veranstaltung = v.uid')
               ->where(
                  $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('t.uid', $uid)//$queryBuilder->createNamedParameter('horst')
               )
               ->execute();

            if($record = $statement->fetch()){
                if(is_array($record) && mb_strlen(trim($record['urltitel']))){
                    $beginn = new \DateTime();
                    $beginn->setTimestamp(intval($record['beginn']));
                    return $uid.'--'.str_replace('--', '-', $record['urltitel'].'-'.$beginn->format('d-m-Y') );
                }
            }
        }
        return $value;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $value
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function resolve(string $value): ?string
    {
        return intval(explode('--',$value)[0]);
    }
}
```

config:

```
routeEnhancers:
  REDACTEDveranstaltungen_veranstaltungen:
    type: Extbase
    extension: REDACTEDVeranstaltungen
    plugin: Veranstaltungen
    routes: 
      - { routePath: '/themenbereiche/{thema_titel}', _controller: 'Termin::search',  _arguments: {'thema_titel': 'veranstaltungsarten/0'} }
      - { routePath: '/veranstaltung/{termin_titel}', _controller: 'Veranstaltung::show',  _arguments: {'termin_titel': 'termin'} }
    aspects:
      termin_titel:
        #type: PersistedAliasMapper
        #tableName: 'tx_REDACTEDveranstaltungen_domain_model_termin'
        #routeFieldName: 'uid'
        type: TerminValueMapper
      thema_titel:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: 'sys_category'
        routeFieldName: 'title'
```

Comment: cHash is usually added if the parameters are not enough to resolve the request uniquely.

Comment: perhaps this question beside answer is helping: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57637619/typo3-slug-not-working-with-multiple-arguments-in-flink-action

Comment: I know for certain that all generated URLs are unique, since the termin.uid is always part of the URL. There are, also, no other arguments in the URL beside controller, action and termin. By, the way, the thema_titel PersistedAliasMapping is very similar and does not append the cHash. Thanks for trying to help, tho. Any idea on how to further debug this problem?

Comment: for the documentation part: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Routing/ExtendingRouting.html#writing-custom-enhancers and the examples also contain a custom enhancer iirc - for the cHash part: the cHash is also added if the restrictions are too loose or more than (I think) 10000 possibilities are returned. For further debugging try in `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Routing\PageRouter::buildPageArguments` and `Packages/TYPO3.CMS/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Routing/PageRouter.php:311`

Comment: Thanks, @Susi, this was of immense help. In many hours of googling I never came accross that page. The solution was, in fact, to extend the  StaticMappableAspectInterface instead of the PersistedMappableAspectInterface. Want to turn your comment into an answer for points?

Comment: @j4k3 answered :) Happy that helped - the documentation is pretty new, so maybe google is not up-to-date yet.

Comment: @Susi True that. I'm glad Google finally caught up the "master" being the new newest version branch :)

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of the routing feature - specifically extending routing - can be found at https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Routing/ExtendingRouting.html#writing-custom-enhancers

For debugging issues with cHash use the following two places as a starting point: 
`\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Routing\PageRouter::buildPageArguments` and `Packages/TYPO3.CMS/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Routing/PageRouter.php:311`

When extending routing, pay attention of whether you need to write a custom route enhancer (if you need to manipulate how the full route looks like and gets resolved) or a custom aspect (if you want to manipulate how a single route parameter (“variable”) gets mapped and resolved). Both also have sub-types (enhancers and decorators, static or dynamic mappers) which you can find in the documentation.