# TYPO3 routing and aspect - remove cHash from URL

Tags: typo3, url-routing, typo3-9.x

With TYPO3 9.5 I try to manage the URLs from my extension with a custom aspect. The url-generation works but there is a cHash appended. First, I don't want this cHash (it's unnecessary here) and second the cHash breaks the functionality of the link (I get a cHash-comparsion-error).

I read https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/9.5/Feature-86365-RoutingEnhancersAndAspects.html#impact another time about the dynamic parameters and cHash. To remove cHash I should add aspects for all placeholders. I have just one placeholder and an aspect for this, but cHash is present.

raw-url looks like this:

`&tx_psoabilling_pi1[action]=showband&tx_psoabilling_pi1[controller]=Band&tx_psoabilling_pi1[band]=564&cHash=jkg24hwek8ufhqwezweklfzh`

it's rendered to something like this:

`2019-thisisaname?cHash=o28z3hkwejghweuhzlk`

Here the part from config.yaml:

```
 PsoabillingPlugin:
    type: Extbase
    extension: Psoabilling
    plugin: Pi1
    routes:
      - routePath: '/{yearandbandname}'
        _controller: 'Band::showband'
        _arguments: 
          yearandbandname: band
    defaultController: 'Band::listyear'
    aspects:
      yearandbandname:
        type: BandAndYearMapper
```

**BandAndYearMapper.php**

```
<?php

namespace EnzephaloN\ThemePsoa\Routing\Aspect;

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Routing\Aspect\PersistedMappableAspectInterface;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Site\SiteLanguageAwareTrait;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\ConnectionPool;

class BandAndYearMapper implements PersistedMappableAspectInterface{

    use SiteLanguageAwareTrait;

    /**
     * @param string $value
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function generate(string $value): ?string{
        if($uid=intval($value)){
            $queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getQueryBuilderForTable('tx_psoabilling_domain_model_band');
            $statement = $queryBuilder
               ->select('b.uid', 'b.name', 'y.year')
               ->from('tx_psoabilling_domain_model_band','b')
               ->leftJoin('b', 'tx_psoabilling_domain_model_year', 'y', 'b.year = y.uid')
               ->where(
                  $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('b.uid', $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter($uid))
               )
               ->execute();
            if($record = $statement->fetch()){
                if(is_array($record)){
                    return $record['year']. "-" .str_replace(" ","-",trim(strtolower($record['name'])));
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $value
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function resolve(string $value): ?string{
        $year = substr($value, 0, 4);
        $name = str_replace("-", " ", substr($value, 5));
        $queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)->getQueryBuilderForTable('tx_psoabilling_domain_model_band');
        $statement = $queryBuilder
            ->select('b.uid')
            ->from('tx_psoabilling_domain_model_band','b')
            ->leftJoin('b', 'tx_psoabilling_domain_model_year', 'y', 'b.year = y.uid')
            ->where(
                $queryBuilder->expr()->andX(
                    $queryBuilder->expr()->eq('y.year', $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter($year)),
                    $queryBuilder->expr()->orX(
                        $queryBuilder->expr()->like('b.name', $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter($name)),
                        $queryBuilder->expr()->like('b.name', $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter(substr($value, 5))), // if there was a - inside the bandname
                        $queryBuilder->expr()->like('b.name', $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter(substr($value, 5, strpos($name, " ")-1).'%')) // just find by beginning
                    )
                )
            )
            ->execute();
        if($record = $statement->fetch()){
            return (string)$record['uid'];
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

How can the cHash be removed??

Comment: Can you check if my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57649210/typo3-routeenhancer-with-custom-valuemapper helps?

Comment: Hello @Susi . I don't see at which point your answer can help me. In my optinion all is correct - one placeholder => one aspect = should run without cHash, but does not. Don't know how and what to debug. Thats while I'm asking.

Comment: What and where to debug was part of my answer. In general: how does your aspect look like, is it a staticMappable (no cHash in general) or not? Can you post your aspect?

Comment: Hello @Susi . I added the code from my aspect. It just grabs name and associated year from the db and puts this together. The result has to be similar to my former realurl-config. I did many looks at \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Routing\PageRouter::buildPageArguments but saw no point where I can start with debugging... Hope you can help me.

Comment: Can you try switching the interface to StaticMappableAspectInterface ?

Comment: Hello @Susi . Today I tried the PersistedPatternMapper with uid and name, which worked. But I need an url with year and name, where year is another table.

Comment: The PersistedPatternMapper also implements StaticMappableAspectInterface which was my suggestion above. I guess it would also work for you if you'd implement that.

Comment: Hello @Susi . That's it! Switched to "implements StaticMappableAspectInterface" and it works like expected! Great! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Susi wrote, switching to StaticMappableAspectInterface was the solution. The class now starts with:

```
<?php

namespace EnzephaloN\ThemePsoa\Routing\Aspect;

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Routing\Aspect\StaticMappableAspectInterface;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Site\SiteLanguageAwareTrait;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\ConnectionPool;

class BandAndYearMapper implements StaticMappableAspectInterface{
```